# Show table border with border collapse

Tags: html, css

I've made a table with border collapse applied to it. This is standard in the css for all of our tables.

My new table requires a small section beside the row header to be a color. Because the td tag has padding on it, a div doesn't stretch the full distance. Same problem would apply to adding a new table cell to contain only the colored bit.

The idea was that adding a border would solve the problem, and it would work, except for the border-collapse. So the problem is demonstrated here http://jsfiddle.net/dtv6P/ where you can see the left border specifically applied to the one cell, is outside the visible bounds of the table. I've tried to apply "border-collapse: separate" to the cell but that doesn't seem to work, so any ideas?

edit* the color is selected from an array based on the line of data

basic idea code (not my actual code)

```
<head>
<style>
td {
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 4px;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td><td>3a</td></tr>
<tr><td style="border-left: 10px solid;">1b</td><td>2b</td><td>3b</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2c</td><td>3c</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do: is it to add color to your first cells?
Or are you trying to make that border "go inside" the cell?
If so, applying a background-image would do the trick? Edit: just read your edit about picking the color... I may recommend to use a container dedicated to the color to whom you can apply the selected one, inside your TD, with an absolute positionning

Comment: I'm trying to add a color to the first row cell yes (not all of them), but not to all of the cell. Preferably I was looking to make the border go inside the cell. Can I apply a background image without making an actual image file? Or a background color to the td without having it apply to the whole thing ?

Comment: Mmm ok no. The background can't apply to the whole td. That's the point. Just the first bit of that first cell. With regards to your edit, I did try using a div with a top & bottom of 0, but that doesn't get around the padding that the td uses.

Comment: I tried too... it's a bit tricky and you're right, with the padding you'll get a white space. Not sure you could get what you want without using a little javascript too...

Comment: If you had an idea of how to fix it with javascript I'd definately take a look

Comment: My current solution that is working is to give a `colspan` to the headings row and unaffected rows, and then add an additional cell to the row itself giving it a background color. If anyone has a better solution..

Answer (score 0):

I found this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp and found it to be helpful.

```
<head>
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse
}
table,  td {
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 4px;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td><td>3a</td></tr>
<tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td><td>3b</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2c</td><td>3c</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm asking for suggestions on what else to do, not links to reference sites about the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that works... but you need to know the height of your contents... it's not very convenient, but works.

```
<table>
<tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td><td>3a</td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="withColor"></div>1b</td><td>2b</td><td>3b</td></tr>
<tr><td>1c</td><td>2c</td><td>3c</td></tr>
</table>
```

with your css

```
td {
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 4px;
height:20px;
}
td div.withColor {
position:absolute;
margin:-4px 0 0 -4px;
border-left:4px solid red;
height:28px;
}
```